# turbo trainer on wtb 27.5 sx19 wheel is it possible

Tags: turbo-trainer

I have a norco 7.1 charger 2015 bike. I'm looking to put some miles on a turbo trainer

http://www.halfords.com/cycling/turbo-trainers/trainers/tacx-blue-matic-folding-magnetic-trainer

I'm a noob who need to know if it's possible for me:

a)get a tyre that will fit my rim

or

b)get a cheap and nasty rim to fit 27.5 1.25inch tyre

Comment: As far a your  option b, it can be difficult to find a decent quality 27.5 wheel and tire on a budget. There is no reason you couldn't use a used 26" wheel and a slick tire. It wouldn't have to be a disc wheel since brakes aren't needed on the trainer.

Answer (score 1):

Trainers are hard on bikes and on tyres/tires.  You want a cheap hard-wearing tyre for the rear.   Grip and tread are mostly irrelevant, and even a mostly worn tyre is probably fine.  Get every bit of usage out of the rubber.

Some people choose to have a spare rear wheel to swap out for convenience, because that's less work than swapping the tyre.

Others have a dedicated trainer bike permanently mounted in the trainer. Sometimes they even have no front wheel, purely for space saving.

Aside - Consider setting up a fan to replicate the passage of air.  Its hot and sweaty working on a trainer without airflow.